# Order by distance

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgis, gist-index

If I have a query returning nearby cafes:

```
SELECT * FROM cafes c WHERE (
   ST_DWithin(
   ST_GeographyFromText(
     'SRID=4326;POINT(' || c.longitude || ' ' || c.latitude || ')'
   ),
   ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-76.000000 39.000000)'),
     2000
   )
)
```

How do I select distance, and order by distance as well?
Is there a more efficient way than this one:

```
 SELECT id, 
 ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-76.000000 39.000000)'),
             ST_GeographyFromText(
             'SRID=4326;POINT(' || c.longitude || ' ' || c.latitude || ')')      
             ) as distance 
 FROM cafes c
   WHERE (
   ST_DWithin(
     ST_GeographyFromText(
     'SRID=4326;POINT(' || c.longitude || ' ' || c.latitude || ')'
   ),
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-76.000000 39.000000)'),
   2000
 )
 ) order by distance
```

Comment: Can you use the distance in your `WHERE` clause?  Like comparing it with a threshold?

Comment: can you please elaborate on that I'm not sure that I understand what you mean? thanks

Comment: I was thinking that a point being inside a geometry or nor farther than a given distance may be more or less equivalent in some cases.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**First**, use

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(c.longitude, c.latitude),4326)::geography
```

instead of

```
ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || c.longitude || ' ' || c.latitude || ')')
```

[The manual:](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)

> `ST_MakePoint` while not being OGC compliant is generally faster and
> more precise than `ST_GeomFromText` and `ST_PointFromText`. It is also
> easier to use if you have raw coordinates rather than WKT.

**Next**, to make the query shorter and only enter search parameters once (without much effect on performance), use a **subquery** (or CTE):

```
SELECT id
     , ST_Distance(t.x
                 , ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(c.longitude, c.latitude),4326)::geography) AS dist
FROM   cafes c
    , (SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-76.000000 39.000000)')) AS t(x)
WHERE  ST_DWithin(t.x
                , ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(c.longitude, c.latitude),4326)::geography, 2000)
ORDER  BY dist;
```

**Finally**, you need a **GiST index** to make this fast for big tables. [The manual on `ST_DWithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html):

> This function call will automatically include a bounding box
> comparison that will make use of any indexes that are available on the geometries.

You could get this to work with a [functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on the expression at the start of the answer. But I would store a `geography` type column to begin with (let's name it `thegeog`) and create a plain GiST index like:

```
CREATE INDEX cafes_thegeog_gist ON cafes USING gist(thegeog);
```

Arriving at this much simpler and faster query:

```
SELECT id, ST_Distance(t.x, thegeog) AS distance 
FROM   cafes c
    , (SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-76.000000 39.000000)')) AS t(x)
WHERE  ST_DWithin(t.x, thegeog, 2000)
ORDER  BY distance;
```

Updated to match `geography` with `geography`, as pointed out by @LR1234567 in the comment. As an alternative, you could work with `geometry`. All functions used here work for both (except for `ST_MakePoint`, hence the appended cast). [What's the difference?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26082/7244) See:

- [Why is my spatial query slower in Postgres 13 than in Postgres 11?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300292/why-is-my-spatial-query-slower-in-postgres-13-than-in-postgres-11/300294#300294)

If you want to get the *n* nearest cafes instead all within a radius, consider a [**"nearest neighbour" search**](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html). Often more convenient.

Comment: You shouldn't mix geometry with geography.  You should do: ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(c.longitude, c.latitude),4326)::geography  - note that ST_MakePoint returns a geometry.

Comment: @LR1234567: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 + acc, pretty awesome answer I hope that will help many people as well

Comment: Hi Erwin I did everything like you wrote, I created a geography column (thegeog), created index and I dumped all the latlongs into it `UPDATE cafes SET
  thegeog = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);` Do I still need to use that part where I `select ST_GeographyFromText .... AS t(x)` now that I have this column populated? Can I take advantage of that column and ask nearby that directly instead of specifying lat/long?

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow: Yes, as demonstrated in my last query.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter your last query works well and I'm using it right now but instead of providing coordinates to look for nearby cafes, can I search based on the geography column? Are lat/long columns redundant in my table? Should I delete them all together and just save lat/long in the geography column? Or should I ask a new question for this? Sorry about all the questions

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow: Search for *what*? Obviously, you need a point of reference in your search. You could search cafes around a specified cafe ...`lat` / `long` are redundant now. If there's more to it, start a new question. You can always reference this one for context.

Comment: I need to join a table and getting; ` There is an entry for table "groups", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query` Any ideas on why groups isn't available in the join?

SELECT groups.id, ST_Distance(t.x, locations.center) AS distance 
FROM   groups, (SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-76.000000 39.000000)')) AS t(x)
JOIN locations
ON groups.location_id = locations.id
WHERE  ST_DWithin(t.x, locations.center, 20000)
ORDER  BY distance;

Comment: @Underwater_developer: This should work: `SELECT groups.id, ST_Distance(t.x, locations.center) AS distance
FROM groups
JOIN locations ON groups.location_id = locations.id
, (SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-76.000000 39.000000)')) AS t(x)
WHERE ST_DWithin(t.x, locations.center, 20000)
ORDER BY distance;` Because: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598292/939860 Please ask your questions as ***question***.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for the reply. I wrote up my next question. In the end I managed to avoid the error in my comment by switching the order entities in the FROM statement (which you can see in my new question)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307320/cte-clause-not-able-to-be-used-in-final-order-by-statement