# PostGIS radius query

Tags: postgresql, spatial, postgis

I have a table setup with the following columns, and it contains about 100K listing of data.

```
Column: address   |  Type: Text
Column: geo_point | Type: geometry(Point,4326)
```

My question is for each listing, how do I write the radius search query to find all the listing within 5 miles?

Answer (score 4):

Best use [**`ST_DWithin()`**](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) in a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT t.*, neighbor.*  -- or only selected columns
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl t1
   WHERE  ST_DWithin(t.geo_point, t1.geo_point, 5000 * 1.609344)
   ) neighbor ON true
WHERE t.address = 'my_address';  -- to restrict to a particular address
```

`1.609344` being the factor for converting miles to kilometers. [Source: Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile) Assuming meter as unit! [The documentation:](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

> For Geometries: The distance is specified in units defined by the
>   spatial reference system of the geometries. For this function to make
>   sense, the source geometries must both be of the same coordinate
>   projection, having the same SRID.
>
> For geography units are in meters

I think your SRID 4326 uses degrees, *not* meters. Instructions in this related answer:

- [ST_DWithin takes parameter as degree , not meters , why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8445283/939860)

You need an **index** on `geo_point` to make this fast (used by `ST_DWithin()` automatically):

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_geo_point_gist ON tbl USING gist (geo_point);
```

A GiST index can also be used to identify *nearest* neighbors (in combination with a maximum number - `LIMIT`).

Related:

- [Order by distance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60619/order-by-distance/60711#60711)

Comment: Thanks!!! The query ran fine. Howerver, I getting the following error: NOTICE:  gserialized_gist_joinsel: jointype 1 not supported

Comment: @user1187968; I think the message is safe to ignore: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2342

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this too,

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*  -- or only selected columns
FROM   tbl t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl AS t2
WHERE ST_DWithin(t1.geo_point, t2.geo_point, 5000 * 1.609344);
```

I assume it gets planned substantially faster. You should still use the Index as suggested in Erwin's answer.