# Searching for a close numeric match on spatial coordinates

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, spatial, nearest-neighbor

I have a large Postgres table contain geographic positions (latitude and longitude) both fields are indexed, and both are defined as `NUMERIC(9,6)`.

If I run a query looking for an exact position match, something like this:

```
WHERE latitude  = 1.234567890123456789
AND   longitude = 9.876543210987654321
```

Then get a very fast response, but I get very few results because the database is searching for a very precise match.

For my purposes, I'm looking for positions that match to within a few meters so a match to 4 or 5 decimal places should be fine. This gives me the results I'm looking for:

```
WHERE ABS(latitude  - 1.234567890123456789) < 0.0001
AND   ABS(longitude - 9.876543210987654321) < 0.0001
```

But NOT the performance (it can take 5 minutes to run, compared to a fraction of a second for the exact search)

Next I tried rounding the precision down:

```
WHERE ROUND( latitude, 4) = ROUND( 1.234567890123456789, 4)
AND   ROUND( longitude,4) = ROUND( 9.876543210987654321, 4)
```

Again, same problem. Got the results I wanted, but took far too long.

So, my question is how can I search for a close match between two numbers, without losing performance?

UPDATE - SOLVED:
As a couple of commenters have observed, using `BETWEEN` seems to work fine.

Comment: your where clause has to lok up every single row to see if it fits there is no short cut. Besides, please read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions/3035#3035  for such geographical problems exist https://postgis.net/

Comment: Can you store a copy of the less precise `latitude` and `longitude` in additional fields on the same table, and create the index on those new fields? By pre-staging the data this way, it'll already be materialized in a form that you likely can more efficiently query the index for. Otherwise like nbk stated, functions and arithmetic in the `WHERE` clause is what's causing your inefficiencies and there's not many other ways around it other than pre-staging the data in the format you need (i.e. less precision in this case).

Comment: Try `WHERE latitude  BETWEEN 1.234567890123456789 - 0.0001 AND 1.234567890123456789 + 0.0001
AND longitude BETWEEN 9.876543210987654321 - 0.0001 AND 9.876543210987654321 + 0.0001`

Comment: Do not use `WHERE ABS(coordinate  - @position) < @accuracy`, use `WHERE coordinate BETWEEN @position - @accuracy AND @position + @accuracy`. *both fields are indexed* Do you mean one composite index or two separate indices? the former is preferred...

Answer (score 1):

The smart and fast solution for this class of problems is an index-backed **"nearest neighbor"** search.

For the record: if you want precise results with spatial data use **PostGis** and operate with `geometry` or `geography` types. [Here is a starting point.](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/projection.html) And operate with [`ST_DWithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). Examples:

- [Order by distance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60619/order-by-distance/60711#60711)
- [PostGIS radius query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120522/postgis-radius-query/120537#120537)

Sticking to your setup (2-D points, no PostGis), and ignoring the additional approximation error of handling spatial data in a 2-D plain, which seems negligible for the case at hand - I suggest a [space-partitioned GiST index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spgist-intro.html) ([on an expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) in your case):

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_location_spgist_idx ON tbl USING SPGIST (point(longitude, latitude));
```

Why SP-Gist? See:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22111524/939860)
- https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-12-implementing-k-nearest-neighbor-space-partitioned-generalized-search-tree-indexes/

To get a maximum of 10 "nearest neighbors" in next to no time:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY point (longitude, latitude)
      <-> point '(9.876543210987654321,1.234567890123456789)'
LIMIT  10;
```

You can then filter the ones close enough. To get a maximum of 10 closest *within a maximum distance*:

```
SELECT *, ((longitude - 9.876543210987654321) ^ 2
        + (latitude   - 1.234567890123456789) ^ 2) AS squared_dist
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ((longitude - 9.876543210987654321) ^ 2
      + (latitude  - 1.234567890123456789) ^ 2) < 0.000000001  -- or whatever
ORDER  BY point (longitude, latitude)
      <-> point '(9.876543210987654321,1.234567890123456789)'
LIMIT  10;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=04625fcb144963460cf5dcd04bddf818)*

I use a *squared* distance to get nearest neighbors based on simple [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). The beauty of it: the calculation is only performed on the nearest neighbors, so it's still very fast when the calculation gets more expensive - even in big tables.